# Connection error while connecting to cloudant DB from localhost

Tags: nosql, localhost, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am trying to connect to cloudantDB from local.
This is the code that I get from the IBM example and it is working on deployed version online.

```
   try {
        System.out.println("Connecting to Cloudant : " + user);

        //This works
        CloudantClient client = ClientBuilder.account(user)
                .username(user)
                .password(password)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        System.out.println("Connected to Cloudant : " + user);

        //This doesn't works and fire the errror Show the server version
        System.out.println("Server Version: " + client.serverVersion());

        //This doesn't works and fire the error to. Show databases
        System.out.println("Dbs: " + client.getAllDbs());

        return client;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to connect", e);
    }
```

And from localhost I have this error:

```
[ERROR   ] Failed to get cookie from server, response code 503, cookie authentication will not be attempted again 
[err] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to connect to repository
[err]   at it.sinesy.nosql.CloudantClientMgr.createClient(CloudantClientMgr.java:110)
[err]   at it.sinesy.nosql.CloudantClientMgr.initClient(CloudantClientMgr.java:45)
[err]   at it.sinesy.nosql.CloudantClientMgr.getDB(CloudantClientMgr.java:117)
[err]   at it.sinesy.nosql.ResourceServlet.getDB(ResourceServlet.java:307)
[err]   at it.sinesy.nosql.ResourceServlet.get(ResourceServlet.java:110)
[err]   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor751.invoke(Unknown Source)
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:646)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
[err]   at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.service(IBMRestServlet.java:96)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[err] Caused by: com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: 503 Service Unavailable: service_unavailable: Service unavailable
[err]   at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.execute(CouchDbClient.java:526)
[err]   at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.executeToInputStream(CouchDbClient.java:574)
[err]   at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.get(CouchDbClient.java:320)
[err]   at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.serverVersion(CouchDbClient.java:240)
[err]   at com.cloudant.client.api.CloudantClient.serverVersion(CloudantClient.java:272)
[err]   at it.sinesy.nosql.CloudantClientMgr.createClient(CloudantClientMgr.java:103)
[err]   ... 45 more
```

I'm not behind a proxy..
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you get the server / account configuration?

Comment: @data_henrik from cloudant console "generate api key" I get the account/password and the database name.
All the rest is done by cloudant library "cloudant-client 2.7.0"

Answer (score 3):

> from cloudant console "generate api key" I get the account/password
>   and the database name

If you are using an API key then the account name is not the same as the username. In your example they are both called using `user`

`ClientBuilder.account(account_name) // needs to be the part before .cloudant.com
              .username(api_key_user) // needs to be the API key`

Secondly, API keys are per database so don't have permission to do `getAllDbs()`.

FWIW the `.build()` doesn't actually connect to Cloudant it just builds a `CloudantClient` object, no HTTP requests happen until needed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
User and password MUST be created from Cloudant service -> Service Credntial -> New Credential.

I was using wrong credential created from the cloudant -> database -> permissions -> Generate API Key.